# Error: La referencia a un miembro no compartido requiere una referencia de objeto

Tags: vb.net, object

Estoy trabajando en 3 capas a pulmón (otra historia), pero el problema que tengo es el mensaje de error (título de la pregunta) pese a que hago como dice el ejemplo del profesor y ese funciona, pero el mio no.

Del Formulario ingreso los datos de login del usuario y los doy a la función de lógica que se comunica con la capa de datos.

```
Public Class frmLogin
    Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIngresar.Click

        Dim loggeo = Usuario.Ingreso(txtUsuario.Text, txtPassword.Text)

        If loggeo Then
            MsgBox("Bienvenido.")
            frmMenuAdmin.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

En la Capa Lógica, le doy a la capa de datos el usuario y contraseña que pasó el formulario:

```
Public Class Usuario

    Public Function Ingreso(ByVal usuario As String, ByVal password As String)
        Try
            Dim l As New CapaDeDatos.Usuarios
            l.user = usuario
            l.pass = password
            l.Login()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Pero pasa que me da el error de referencia en el formulario en la línea de:
`Dim loggeo = Usuario.Ingreso(txtUsuario.Text, txtPassword.Text)` en referencia a `Function Usuario.Ingreso(usuario As String, password As String) As Object`.

Comment: Dónde y como define txtUsario y txtPassword?

Comment: son los textbox del formulario frmLogin

Comment: Y está seguro que la ortografía es correcta?

Comment: El error era la interfaz entre la silla y el teclado...

Answer (score 1):

El error estaba en que no instanciaba la clase Ingreso mediante un objeto desde el formulario, el código es el siguiente:

```
Public Class frmLogin

        Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIngresar.Click

            Dim i As New Usuario
            Dim loggeo As Boolean
            loggeo = i.Ingreso(txtUsuario.Text, txtPassword.Text)

            If loggeo Then
                MsgBox("Bienvenido.")
                frmMenuAdmin.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                MsgBox("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.")
            End If

        End Sub

End Class
```

Gracias Duston por tu tiempo.